# How to install secure MySQL using Ansible on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql

I am installing MySQL using ansible apt module but i can't configure MySQL with password.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Please review this article [How do I ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your questions to meet standards enforced here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Ansible Module, it provides an easy and idempotent way for `mysql_secure_installation` in Ansible

---

**Example - with a fresh MySQL Installation**

```yaml
- name: test mysql_secure_installation
  mysql_secure_installation:
    login_password: ''
    new_password: password22
    user: root
    login_host: localhost
    hosts: ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1']
    change_root_password: true
    remove_anonymous_user: true
    disallow_root_login_remotely: true
    remove_test_db: true
  register: mysql_secure

# To see detailed output
- debug:
    var: mysql_secure
```

**Example - Change an existing root password**

```yaml
- name: test mysql_secure_installation
  mysql_secure_installation:
    login_password: password22
    new_password: password23
    user: root
    login_host: localhost
    hosts: ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1']
```

> **For usage**: All you have to do is create a dir called `library` in your `playbooks or role's dir` and copy the `mysql_secure_installation.py` to it,

*you can find a Full example in the following Link*

https://github.com/eslam-gomaa/mysql_secure_installation_Ansible

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a role where you can learn from it. Anyways, try to find this kind of "how to"s in gists, there are tons of docs that can solve your problem.

[MySQL Secure Installation Ansible Role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql/blob/master/tasks/secure-installation.yml)

Comment: Please read the section "[How to answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)" in the Help for this website: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: "Here you are a role where you can learn from it." is enough to point that this link relates to the statement.